# Firestore adding 2 documents execution time

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any difference between those 2 in terms of execution time?

```
collectionReference.add(testObject)
 .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

     collectionReference.add(testObject2);
    }
  })
```

And

```
collectionReference.add(testObject);

collectionReference.add(testObject2);
```

In the first case second adding will be executed after first one is finished, is the same thing happening in second case? Is the second adding queried and is waiting for first to finish, or are they running in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be a difference between the execution time of these two.

In the first case you're waiting for the first write to be completed on the server, before sending the second write to the server. In a diagram:

```
 Client                            Server
   |                                  |
   |---- Send document to write ----->|
   |                                  |
   |                                  |
   |<----- Response from server ------|
   |---- Send document to write ----->|
   |                                  |
   |                                  |
   |<----- Response from server ------|
   |                                  |
```

In the second case, the second write is sent to the server right after the first write was sent.

```
 Client                            Server
   |                                  |
   |---- Send document to write ----->|
   |---- Send document to write ----->|
   |                                  |
   |                                  |
   |                                  |
   |<----- Response from server ------|
   |<----- Response from server ------|
   |                                  |
```

The difference in performance between these two is the latency of the connection between you and the server.

Note that this is just the theoretical difference, and likely there are many more factors influencing the performance.